# How to parse a simple XML file using Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xml-parsing, xcode4.2

dont get to harsh on me for asking this question, I know this has been asked many times. But the examples I found on the internet are either old or I am having difficulties to port them on to iOS5-Xcode 4.2.1. So I am really looking for a updated simple example where I can parse a simple XML file from an URL, store the values and display them in a tableView. I am looking for some working examples using NSXMLParser. In case if one of you guys have some info about where I can find a working example/internet link which I can follow and make it work on my machine, so that I can play and get some hands of experience on dealing with XML data, before I go on to work with the complex XML data files.

Any one who can post some code is also highly appreciated, as it would help beginners like me.

Comment: To give you my opinion, I think you shouldn't use NSXMLParser unless you need some specific fine-granular control. There are plenty of frameworks (TouchXML etc. just google) out there that can make your life that much easier. Here, read this http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: Hey Raaks, if you find something that helps you can you post back here?  I'm searching for this too.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi user418775, I found a very good video tutorial which uses NSXMLParser, check this out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PZlaDVsLBk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you checked this tutorial of parsing XML data with NSXMLParser -

http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

i think your are looking for this.

Also there is an another good way to do this is using TBXML framework - https://github.com/71squared/TBXML